# TensorFlow sentiment analysis: use own data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been using the following code from the TFLearn examples:

```
"""
Simple example using LSTM recurrent neural network to classify IMDB
sentiment dataset.
References:
    - Long Short Term Memory, Sepp Hochreiter & Jurgen Schmidhuber, Neural
    Computation 9(8): 1735-1780, 1997.
    - Andrew L. Maas, Raymond E. Daly, Peter T. Pham, Dan Huang, Andrew Y. Ng,
    and Christopher Potts. (2011). Learning Word Vectors for Sentiment
    Analysis. The 49th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational
    Linguistics (ACL 2011).
Links:
    - http://deeplearning.cs.cmu.edu/pdfs/Hochreiter97_lstm.pdf
    - http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/
"""
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import os
import tflearn
from tflearn.data_utils import to_categorical, pad_sequences
from tflearn.datasets import imdb

# IMDB Dataset loading
train, test, _ = imdb.load_data(path='imdb.pkl', n_words=100,
                                valid_portion=0.1)

trainX, trainY = train
testX, testY = test

# Data preprocessing
# Sequence padding
trainX = pad_sequences(trainX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
testX = pad_sequences(testX, maxlen=100, value=0.)
# Converting labels to binary vectors
trainY = to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes=2)
testY = to_categorical(testY, nb_classes=2)

# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data([None, 100])
net = tflearn.embedding(net, input_dim=10000, output_dim=128)
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.001,
                         loss='categorical_crossentropy')

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True,
          batch_size=32)
```

The model trains successfully and manages to get 83% accuracy on the test set. What I want to do now is apply this trained model to new unseen data.

For example, something like: `model.predict("I am very happy today")` should return a positive sentiment value.

I am new to TensorFlow and Python, since I've been using R to do sentiment analysis and it looks like using an LSTM model in TensorFlow has significantly higher accuracy than anything I've used in the past.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.